# Delete an item in array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a document as

> {
>           "_id" : ObjectId("5de2a0a2336a4c5adc3fc25c"),
>           "image" : {
>                   "otherImages" : [
>                           {
>                                   "imageUrl" : "HL2370207N_1575195338958.jpg",
>                                   "status" : true
>                           },
>                           {
>                                   "imageUrl" : "HL2370207N_1575195373805.jpg",
>                                   "status" : true
>                           },
>                           {
>                                   "imageUrl" : "HL2370207N_1575195382992.jpg",
>                                   "status" : true
>                           }
>                   ]
>           } }

I have  to  delete an item of an otherImages array whose imageUrl is "HL2370207N_1575195382992.jpg"
$pull  cannot  applied since it is  under node image which is not an array. please give any guidance . i am new to  the mongoDB

Comment: Hum, why do you think *`$pull` cannot be applied*? Could you show your query?

Comment: db.userdetails.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { image: {OtherImages: { $elemMatch: { imageUrl: "HL2370207N_1575195382992.jpg" } } } }}
  
) 





and  the  error is




 WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 2,
                "errmsg" : "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"
        }
})

Answer (score 1):

I think you can specify the value you want to delete. Like so:

```
{ $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition> } }
```

Source & examples: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/